# Aurelia Validation @ensure decorator deprecated?

Tags: aurelia

I have been using the @ensure decorator but it now log a warning saying that it is depreciated and will be removed in next release (https://github.com/aurelia/validation/commit/0e82a6bb87ba212a01e276faf08d5f05c682b159)

Why it is getting depreciated and is it now the preferred way is to use fluent api to declare validation rules and if so, why? I have tried to Google for an answer but failed. Have asked on gitter but not yet get replied, and the demo site (http://aurelia.io/validation/#/) still showing usage of @ensure.

A side question on the fluent api's ensure function it takes a magic string like `ensure('classProperty')`. Will this create problem when the js file get minified? I am using typescript and would like to know if there is a type-safe way to do something like `ensure(this.classProperty)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ensure decorator was marked as deprecated because it will be removed. 
The next version should be arriving this week, hopefully, and is a complete rewrite of the plugin.
Minification doesn't touch strings.

My best suggestion for you is to wait a couple of days for the new version. This one is non-officially deprecated. They are only fixing some very important fixes, no new feature will be added.

Bests

Comment: Thanks @Mario for the reply. So for any new development I should be avoiding ensure decorator or not?

Comment: Yes, go for the Fluent API instead. By the way, in the new version, there are decorators also, but several instead of just one

Comment: I see. Last question, I am using typescript and would like to know if there is a type-safe way to do something like ensure(this.classProperty) instead of magic string?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that, I don't use TS :)
By the way, the alpha version of the new validation library is out. Check [here](http://patrickwalters.net/how-aurelia-validatejs-workxs/) and [here](http://patrickwalters.net/how-aurelia-validatejs-workxs/) It looks really promising

Comment: Nice one Mario. Your second link did you mean [this](https://github.com/PWKad/aurelia-validate.js)? The new decorators looks cool, way better than `ensure`. However, I am working on a custom textbox element that I want validation rules to be embedded such that I could turn flags on off on the textbox attribute and toggle different validation like `<my-textbox type="number" required positive min-length="3">`. The new decorators need support logic like `if`.